# Cron Expression that includes from and to time

Tags: cronexpression

I have a difficulty writing a cron expression to schedule events Mon-Saturday every 15 minutes from 4:30 am to 8:30 am.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will take 3 separate Quartz cron expressions to define the times exactly as you want them.

```
0 30 4,5,6,7,8 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT *
0 45 4,5,6,7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT *
0 0,15 5,6,7,8 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT *
```

Edited to add: This Quartz cron expression gets you from 4 am to 8:45 am, just as [fvu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193373/300257) does.

```
0 0/15 4-8 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT *
```

Comment: Thanks... But I really need it in one expression... Would it be possible, if I simplify it to run from 4 to 9?

Comment: @David Shochet: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can solve this problem in one step, so a usable strategy might be to first coarse-filter via crontab:

```
0,15,30,45 4,5,6,7,8 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6 /do-whatever
```

which is almost OK, it will just execute 4:00 4:15 and 8:45, so we filter these at the start of the executed script:

```
# Too early?  Then get out
if [ `date +%H%M` -lt 430 ] ; then
   exit 0
fi
# Too late?  Then get out
if [ `date +%H%M` -gt 830 ] ; then
   exit 0
fi
# start of the original script
....
```

Comment: Thanks... But I really need it in one expression... Would it be possible, if I simplify it to run from 4 to 9? Would not this do it: */15 4-8 * * 1-6

Comment: Well obviously that would work, because you remove the very issue that makes this hard :-).  I just wrote out the statements in full, because I thought it was easier to understand.